# How to allow non-admin user group to copy password reset URL and activation URL?

Tags: users

So, as an Admin, I can copy either the password reset URL or the activation URL. But giving another user group all of the Users permissions (e.g. using `select all` in the permissions tab when editing the group) does not give them the same functionality. Is this a config setting or just not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently that's the expected behavior.  Feel free to add your voice to this feature request, though: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/942

Of course you could always write a plugin that exposed whatever features you wanted to whomever you wanted bypassing Craft's logic.